# Stuck at boot message screen after Alt Ctrl F3

Tags: ubuntu

I had logged into Ubuntu 18.04.4 desktop, then I pressed Alt-Ctrl-F3 to get a TTY and logged in there.

At some point I look up and see the last of the boot messages and Alt-Ctrl-F2 does not get me back to the GUI login.

I can't get anything to change but my programs are still running on my desktop.

What mysterious key did I press and what do I hit to get back?

At this point I would have to power off, and I don't want to lose my work.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the GUI is at F2?  Did you try other F keys?  Does your caps lock LED toggle on and off when you press it?

Comment: no caps light on my keyboard but it is a Logitech three receiver model and it works on the other two PC ... tried F2 thr F6 with Alt Ctrl ...

Comment: ... actually ... CAPs lock does work on the other two PC when I switch ... but never lights on this box.

Comment: I plugged in a wired keyboard and the caps light does not light when I hit caps lock key ... does work when I plug in another PC.

Comment: If the caps lock light LED doesn't toggle, that's usually a "bad thing".  Others may have ideas, but generally if I see that behavior, I end up rebooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out.

I had an IOmega 2 port KVM between my two PC's.

Once I added 4 opto isolated USB devices ... problem went away.

I took to wearing a grounded wrist strap just to avoid static electric effects as well.